# How to save the high score in LIBGDX

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-studio

```
public class spacegame extends ApplicationAdapter {
    SpriteBatch batch;
    Texture background;
    Texture ship;
    Texture gameover;



    float shipY = 0;
    float velocity = 0;
    int gamestate=0;
    float gravity = 2;
    int highscore;
    int score = 0;
    int scoringrock = 0;

    BitmapFont font;

    Circle shiprectangel ;
    // ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer ;

    Rectangle[] rockrectangle;

    float gap = 450;
    float maxrockoffset;
    Random randomgenerator;

    float rockvelocity = 8;

    int numberofrocks = 4;
    float[] rockX = new float[ numberofrocks];
    float[] rockoffset = new float[numberofrocks];
    float distancebetweenrocks;

    Texture rock;
    Texture rock2;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        batch=new SpriteBatch();
        background=new Texture("background.png");
        ship = new Texture("ship.png");
        rock = new Texture("rock.png");
        rock2 = new Texture("rock2.png");
        shiprectangel = new Circle();
    //  shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
        rockrectangle = new Rectangle[numberofrocks];
        gameover = new Texture("gameover.png");

        font = new BitmapFont();
        font.setColor(Color.RED);
        font.getData().setScale(10);

        maxrockoffset = Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2 - gap / 2 - 100;
        randomgenerator = new Random();
        distancebetweenrocks = Gdx.graphics.getWidth() * 3/5;




            startgame();


    }

    public  void startgame() {

        shipY=Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2 - ship.getHeight() / 2;

        for (int i = 0 ; i < numberofrocks; i++) {


            rockoffset[i] = (randomgenerator.nextFloat() - 1.5f) * (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - gap 
       - 400);
            rockX[i] = Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2 - rock.getWidth() / 2 + Gdx.graphics.getWidth() 
       + i * distancebetweenrocks;

            rockrectangle[i] = new Rectangle();


        }

    }

    @Override
    public void render () {

        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(background, 0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        



        if (gamestate == 1) {




            if (rockX[scoringrock] < Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2) {

                score++;

                Gdx.app.log("score", String.valueOf(score));

                if (scoringrock < numberofrocks - 1) {

                    scoringrock++;

                }else{

                    scoringrock = 0;

                }
            }





            if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {


                velocity = -30;


            }

            for (int i = 0 ; i < numberofrocks; i++) {


                if (rockX[i] < - rock.getWidth()) {

                    rockX[i] += numberofrocks *distancebetweenrocks;
                    rockoffset[i] = (randomgenerator.nextFloat() - 1.5f) * 
       (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - gap - 200);

                }else {

                    rockX[i] =  rockX[i] - rockvelocity;



                }

                rockX[i]=rockX[i] - rockvelocity;

                batch.draw(ship, Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2 - ship.getWidth(), shipY);
                font.draw(batch,String.valueOf(score), 100,1000);

                batch.draw(rock, rockX[i], Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2 + gap / 3 + 
      rockoffset[i]);
                //  batch.draw(rock2, Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2 - rock2.getWidth() / 
      2,Gdx.graphics.getHeight() /2 - gap / 2 - rock2.getHeight() + rockoffset);


                rockrectangle[i] = new Rectangle(rockX[i],Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2 + gap / 3 + 
      rockoffset[i], rock.getWidth(), rock.getHeight());

            }

            if (score > highscore) {

                highscore = score;

            }


            if (shipY > 0 ) {

                velocity = velocity + gravity;
                shipY-=velocity;

            }else {

                gamestate = 2;
            }

        }else  if (gamestate == 0){


            font.draw(batch,String.valueOf(highscore), 100, 1000);
            if (Gdx.input.justTouched()) {

                gamestate = 1;


            }

        } else if (gamestate == 2){

            batch.draw(gameover,Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2 - gameover.getWidth() /2 
      ,Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2 - gameover.getHeight() /2 );
            font.draw(batch,String.valueOf(highscore), 100, 1000);


            if (Gdx.input.justTouched()) {

                gamestate = 1;
                startgame();
                score =0;
                scoringrock =0;
                velocity = 0;
            }
        }










    //  shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
    //  shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.RED);

        shiprectangel.set(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() * 1/2, shipY + ship.getHeight() / 
    2,ship.getWidth() * 3/7);

    //  shapeRenderer.circle(shiprectangel.x,shiprectangel.y,shiprectangel.radius);


        for (int i = 0 ; i < numberofrocks; i++) {


        //shapeRenderer.rect(rockX[i],Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2 + gap / 3 + rockoffset[i], 
       rock.getWidth(), rock.getHeight());


        if (Intersector.overlaps(shiprectangel, rockrectangle[i])) {

            gamestate = 2;


        }



        }
        //  shapeRenderer.end();
        batch.end();
    }


}
```

How do I save the high score so whenever the app is opened the high score is displayed. I'd like that when the app is closed the high score is saved and when the app is opened the high score is displayed. I want the users high score to be saved so when they play again I want them to know their high score. There are no errors in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Use a preferences instance. See here

https://www.programmersought.com/article/3503962478/

```
Preferences prefs = Gdx.app.getPreferences("Highscore");
prefs.putInteger("highscore", 10);
prefs.flush();
int highScore = prefs.getInteger("highscore",0);//0 is default for first run
```

Comment: In the create() method read in the highscore value with the default of 0 (because its not initially played). During gameplay you are already handling with the highscore field. Put the persistence in the pause() method (which you currently aren't using) of ApplicationAdapter (as for some targets like Android you don't necessarily know when the application is closed but you do know when its paused). Please mark the answer as accepted if all OK.